# Fazer uma ORDER no MySQL de outra TABLE

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Queria saber se é possível em uma `mysql_query` fazer uma busca e **ORDENÁ-LA** de acordo com atualizações mais recentes de outra tabela por exemplo..

Tenho essa *query*, quando o usuário se loga no chat ele da uma lista de todo os usuários cadastrado, *porem* só mostra os que são seu amigos adicionados.

```
$sqln = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users 
                     WHERE (id = '$id') 
                     OR (id IN (SELECT user2_id FROM following WHERE user1_id='$id'))
                     ORDER BY id ASC
                    ");
```

Mas gostaria de saber se ao invés dele buscar na tabela users, listando de forma `ASC` ordenado pelo `id`, buscar em outra tabela `chat`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onde ele encontraria o id da pessoa, (`id_de`), e traria de volta as mensagem mais recentes pra ficar algo mais atualizado, listando primeiro as conversas mais recentes.. como em aplicações como WHATSAPP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deu para entender?

Comment: Faça outra tabela para as mensagens e associe as mensagens para cada usuário de forma assim continuando a ordenar por id seus usuários e dentro deles suas respectivas mensagens serão registros da tabela mensagens interligada com os "users" poderão ser ordenadas por data.

Comment: mysql_query está sendo descontinuado, eu sugiro que você utilize PDO.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT chat.*,
       users.* 
       FROM chat
       INNER JOIN users ON(users.id=chat.id_de)
       WHERE chat.id_de = '$id_pessoa'
       ORDER BY chat.data DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Como se trata de duas tabelas, você teria que fazer um `JOIN`.
Creio que você possa fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
JOIN chat ON chat.id_de = users.id 
WHERE (id = '$id') 
OR (id IN (SELECT user2_id FROM following WHERE user1_id='$id'))
GROUP BY chat.id_de
ORDER BY chat.data DESC, chat.hora DESC
```

Nesse caso, utilizei o `GROUP BY` para não duplicar os usuários, já que a tabela `chat` poderia ter mais de uma mensagem por pessoa

Comment: não esta listando... :(

Answer (score 0):

Eu ia postar uma resposta parecida com a do @Wallace, mas após alguns testes aqui vi que não ia funcionar pois o Order é realizado depois do Group By, para resolver tem que usar a função Max() para obter a última mensagem de cada user e depois o Order By, mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT u.id, u.nome, MAX(c.data_hora) AS last_msg FROM chat c 
INNER JOIN users u ON c.id_para = u.id
WHERE c.id_de = 1
GROUP BY c.id_para ORDER BY last_msg DESC;
```

Vai listar todos os usuários que já tiveram alguma conversa com o usuário em questão (como no WhatsApp) com a ordenação correta, basta fazer as modificações que vc precisa.

(No meu teste juntei a data e a hora em uma coluna só Timestamp)

Comment: fazer o teste...

Comment: vixii.. me enrolei todo.. kk. Bem ou não consegui ou não estou sabendo formatar o código.. pena

Comment: Mas está dando algum erro? Tente jogar a consulta diretamente no PhpMyAdmin, dê uma olhada no meu teste http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c41/2. Vc pode fazer alterações lá (eu acho, rsrs)